# getaddrinfo() API with systemd

Tags: getaddrinfo

I am facing problem while querying DNS using getaddrinfo() API under a process initiated by systemd. Despite having nameserver entry in /etc/resolv.conf, the query fails to resolve. After few system call traces, it is found that the problem is due to systemd resolution. It seems like, for a process inited by systemd, the getaddrinfo() DNS query routed via systemd while in stand alone mode (i.e. spawned by shell), the query happens normally. I changed the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to add my DNS address and restarted systemd-resolved. Now the DNS query works properly.

Is there anyway to bypass systemd for getaddrinfo() [ex: passing extra flags to hints], and get the work done in usual way?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the genuine `getaddrinfo()` call should always use glibc.

My best guess is that the supposed correlation with systemd process initiation is entirely false. On a systemd system all ordinary processes are either directly or indirectly initiated by systemd.

Network name resolution performed by glibc is not only driven by `/etc/resolv.conf` but also by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. You will probably see resolved mentioned in that file.